# Unable to update body property on activitymimeattachments

Tags: dynamics-crm, microsoft-dynamics

I'm trying to update the content of the body property of an activitymimeattachment. I've tested several methods in a plugin, as well as the webapi. Somehow the property is not updated.

A sample webapi call:

url: https://tenant.crm4.dynamics.com/api/data/v9.0/activitymimeattachments(81f6a467-6c6e-e811-a845-000d3a2a0765)

headers:
Content-type: Application/json

method: PATCH

```
{
"objecttypecode" : "email",
"objectid_activitypointer@odata.bind" : "/emails(08d23aaf-676e-e811-a845-000d3a2a0765)",
"body" : "bWlncmF0ZWQ="
}
```

The webapi returns 204: No content.

If I e.g. add the "subject" property, that will get updated, but the body remains the same.

When I do a post with the exact same body, it runs successful and the attachment is created.

Does anybody know why this happens and how to solve it?

Answer (score 1):

There is an MSDN example using .Net.

[Sample: Create, retrieve, update, and delete an email attachment](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg328344.aspx).

It appears to also set the `FileName`, I suggest you attempt the same.

```
ActivityMimeAttachment _sampleAttachment = new ActivityMimeAttachment
{
    ObjectId = new EntityReference(Email.EntityLogicalName, _emailId),
    ObjectTypeCode = Email.EntityLogicalName,
    Subject = String.Format("Sample Attachment {0}", i),
    Body = System.Convert.ToBase64String(
            new ASCIIEncoding().GetBytes("Example Attachment")),
    FileName = String.Format("ExampleAttachment{0}.txt", i)
};
```

Comment: Thanks, but it doesn't seem to work. It's just very inconsistent. The same patch message I've post above works 10 hours later.

And when I do the same in a plugin, it sometimes works and sometimes doesn't.